# SHA1 hash clarification

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha1

I have the following python code:

```
from hashlib import sha1
secretString=b"this is the secret string"
publicData=b"x10291434"
hash=sha1(publicData+secretString).hexdigest()
```

Now if i send out the `publicData` and `hash` for public consumption. Is this safe? I want to check that when the user provides the `publicData` back it matches the `hash` i originally sent with my `secretKey`.

I just wanted to check that I'm doing this correctly

Comment: You should use a proper [HMAC construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

Comment: What Dan D said. It's easy to use any of the hashlib hash functions with the standard [hmac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) module. For new code you might as well use a stronger hash, eg SHA-256, although as the Wikipedia article mentions, the HMAC construction is resistant to the kinds of attacks that are possible with simple MD5 or SHA-1 hashing.

Comment: Insterad use an HMAC, see: [Keyed-Hashing for Message Authentication](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html#module-hmac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do [HMAC](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

You should try using something like [itsdangerous](https://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/)

```
>>> from itsdangerous import Signer
>>> s = Signer('secret-key')
>>> s.sign('my string')
'my string.wh6tMHxLgJqB6oY1uT73iMlyrOA'
>>> s.unsign('my string.wh6tMHxLgJqB6oY1uT73iMlyrOA')
'my string'
```

Comment: Thanks Jakob if i didn't want to use another library can i generate the HMAC with hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac?

Comment: @johhnyB `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` is excellent. Note that it's designed to be slow to act as a barrier to brute-force attacks. Depending on your application, you may not need that amount of security, and a simple HMAC may be adequate.

Comment: Hi PM 2Ring yes I would prefer speed over security on this occasion. I was just reading about the hmac.new(key, msg=None, digestmod=None) python function. Would that be quicker? does it matter if key is just a random string i pick as a secret key? Or does the key also have to be generated in some special way?

Comment: Use `hmac.new`, a random generated key of sufficient size (128 bits or higher) would be perfect. For the most secure results use SHA-256 or SHA-512 with a key size of 256 or 512 bits.

Comment: Great thanks Maarten and PM for the very informative information

Answer (score -1):

Well, SHA-1 isn't considered a safe hashing algorithm, so no, it isn't safe.

> SHA-1 is no longer considered secure against well-funded opponents. In 2005, cryptanalysts found attacks on SHA-1 suggesting that the algorithm might not be secure enough for ongoing use,[4] and since 2010 many organizations have recommended its replacement by SHA-2 or SHA-3.[5][6][7] Microsoft,[8] Google,[9] Apple[10] and Mozilla[11][12][13] have all announced that their respective browsers will stop accepting SHA-1 SSL certificates by 2017.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

more reading: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html

Comment: It's safe enough for what i want it for I read you still need a lot of computing power to break it. And I'm not dealing with very sensitive information here.

Comment: The way you're using SHA-1 in your question code is _not_ safe. But you can easily make it safe by using SHA-1 as the hash in a HMAC. But as I said in my comment on the question, you might as well use SHA-256 in the HMAC.